# Rank of a matrix up to $n$

Tags: matrices

Suppose I have a matrix, but its elements, rows, and columns, are given in terms of $n$.

For example:
$$
A  =  \left[\begin{matrix}
2&6&10&\cdots &4n-2\\
6&10&14&\cdots &4n+2\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots &\vdots\\
4n-2&4n+2&4n+6&\cdots&8n-6
\end{matrix}\right]
$$
How would I get its rank ?

Comment: What do you mean by "up to $n$"?

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas  mean if it is givin in terms of n.

Comment: I think the 3n+2 should be 4n+2.

Comment: @Edwardffitch I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its rank is equal to $2$.

Let $a_1,\ldots,a_n$, be its rows, then 
$$
a_2-a_1=a_3-a_2=\cdots=a_n-a_{n-1}.
$$ 
This means that all the rows are linear combinations of the first two ones.